# rails ajax_pagination couldn't find file 'history'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, pagination, history.js

I have installed ajax_pagination gem from https://github.com/ronalchn/ajax_pagination

When I restart my server i get this message

> couldn't find file 'history'
>   (in
>   /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/ajax_pagination-0.6.3/lib/assets/javascripts/ajax_pagination.js.erb:3)

and inserted calls in assets manifests, rails version is 3.2.8

I had tried installing a history gem ( https://github.com/philostler/historyjs-rails ) or adding history.js to assets but nothing helps

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in the [jquery-historyjs](https://github.com/wweidendorf/jquery-historyjs) gem, which ajax_pagination depends on. You may want to report an issue on their github repo.

As a work-around, you could create a blank history.js file in app/assets/javascripts and try bringing in [historyjs-rails](https://github.com/philostler/historyjs-rails).

Comment: Ok after I added history.js and ajax_pagination.js file in app/assets/javascripts and ajax_pagination.css to app/assets/stylesheets it worked

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue, all you need to do is:

- Add `gem 'jquery-historyjs'` to your Gemfile,
- Run `bundle install`
- Then `rails generate historyjs:install`

Comment: Good answer. No need to run `rails generate historyjs:install` in my case.