# Rails: How to bind large table to a list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, listview, web

I am new to rails,  most of my experience is with  desktop  (Windows) GUI.

In Windows it is possible to bind s a listview to a database table.
the GUI component hold a only the visible rows of the large table.

if the user scroll up/down to rows not in view,   the control do a "behind the 
scenes"  query in  database to get the new rows to be displayed.

That allows the GUI to map arbitrary large tables with constance memory usage.

I am sure there must be a similar technique for rails, most likely with the aid of 
JQuery but I failed to find it.

I assume the terminology is different is the web world

Comment: Downvoter - care to explain the reason for the downvote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using  [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/)  which did exactly what I was going for

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend a combination of the `will_paginate` gem, AJAX, and some javascript framework (jQuery, prototype, AngularJS, etc.). You can use `will_paginate` to render the first page, and then as the user scrolls down, monitor the scroll progress and load more records. Here's a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/565145/best-way-to-get-will-paginate-working-with-ajax) to get you started.